# CTRL key locks in until I press it again or a shortcut is triggered

Tags: 12.10, keyboard, shortcut-keys

When I do press my <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-key it seems to lock in the pressed state, even after releasing it. Symptoms of this are for example that if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, release it and scroll in my browser window the size of the text changes. After the combination is triggered <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is immediatly released.

It happenend to me only since Ubuntu 12.10. My Dual Boot Windows does not have this problem, so it seems to be an Ubuntu issue.

How do I change this? <kbd>CTRL</kbd> should lose it's function instantly when I release it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like sticky keys got turned on.

To check open 'System Settings'
[image]
Then open 'Universal Access'
[image]
Switch to the 'Typing' tab and turn 'Sticky Keys' off (if its on)
[image]

Hopefully this will fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you ! you are my today's hero, it worked for me, I just wonder how it started acting like this just recently? I have had this ubuntu machine since 2 years ago. (been upgrading since 11.10)

Comment: @Medya  In Windows if you press <shift> 5 times it will activate sticky keys.  It may be the same in Ubuntu.